# Images captured by capturebitmap in QTP are different on different machines

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, qtp, image-capture

I use CaptureBitmap method to save images from IE to local then treat them with JAVA. I test my code on 2 machines in my office, it does well. But then, I copy it onto another one, the image captured by QTP is different, I don't know why, but the sizes are different while the dimensions stay the same...

So did anyone ever come into this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean _the sizes are different while the dimensions stay the same_? Can you post screenshots?

Comment: Hi, I've found the solution, the browser's Internet Option "Compatibilty display" has been activated while the others' not...So, thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the reason, sorry for forgetting to update.

I unchecked the option **"Display the intranet sites in compatibilty display mode"** (I don't know if it's named like this in english, cause my system is in French) in the tab **"Tools"** then option **"Parameters of Compatibilty Display"** in the drop-down menu.